# Texstudio uses MikTex after deinstallation

Tags: miktex, texlive, texstudio, distributions

[image]I had a problem with MikTex and deinstalled it. Afterwards I installed Texlive but Texstudio still uses MikTex. How can I solve this? How can I ensure that the right distribution is used?

Comment: I don't know TexStudio, but probably in the configuration there are still references to MikTex that are (automatically) created when TexStudio was installed. See remarks with https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470164/latex-compile-issue-could-not-start-build-and-view-pdflatex (although for Linux Mint).

Comment: Run on a command line `where pdflatex`. What do you get as answer?